# React application running in a sublink

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to set up my react application to run in `http://mywebsite.com/react` ?

currently it is loading the main page, but it's trying to load the rest of the scripts from `http://mywebsite.com/static` ... instead of `http://mywebsite.com/react/static`

Comment: How are you building the app? Using `create-react-app`?

Comment: That is to say, this isn't as much a React.js question, but a bundler-related question; for instance, Webpack has the `publicPath` option for this.

Comment: You probably have your resources defined as absolute paths. Anything that starts with a hard slash, e.g. `href="/static/foobar.js"` will refer to the absolute root path `http://mywebsite.com/static/foobar.js` no matter where the referred source is. However if you use relative paths, e.g. `href="./static/foobar.js"` (note the `./`) the resource will be found relative to the referred source e.g. `http://mywebsite.com/react/static/foobar.js`.

Comment: The application was created as a visualstudio project, so webpack is misbehaving for some reason